# Save the sys_time type as binary

Tags: c++

In this code that uses the [date](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) library, is it safe to store this type `sys_time` in binary format?
`sys_time` is non-POD but here it looks like `int64`.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <date/date.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace date;

int main () {
    sys_time<chrono::nanoseconds> td;
    istringstream in1{"2017-01-01 22:24:1.000"};
    in1 >> date::parse ("%F %T", td);
    ofstream handle ("f.bin", ios::binary);
    handle.write (reinterpret_cast<char*> (&td), sizeof (td));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say yes, except for endian issues.  I.e. if you save it on a big endian machine and read it with a little endian machine, you'll get the wrong answer.

Since `sys_time<nanoseconds>` is not a POD, you could also just extract its integral POD value and save that as binary:

```
auto i = (td-sys_seconds{})/1ns;
```

or

```
auto i = td.time_since_epoch().count();
```

And then the non-POD issue goes away.  On reading back in, just:

```
sys_time<nanoseconds> td{nanoseconds{i}};
```

I *believe* in C++20 you can even simplify to:

```
sys_time td{nanoseconds{i}};
```

though I'm not yet sure that is implemented anywhere yet.